# Flex 4.5: Refresh only when app is opening and click button

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, flexbuilder

I develop small RSS reader based on one of tutorial. This is a simple application with  on HomeView and when user click Title of RSS items, then app push view on DetailsView.mxml. But I have a small problem. I include a refresh button on HomeView, but every time when I`m scrolling on list or click item and then go back on HomeView list is refreshing. This use a lot of internet connection. Is possible to make this app so that when app is openin, then load (refresh) list then refresh only with press button "Refresh"?

P.S. please, I need simple explain, I`m not a programmer :)

Thanks for any help and here is source code for HomeView:

```
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:rssreader="services.rssreader.*"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        title="Elektro-Vozila" viewActivate="getData()">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;

            protected function getData():void
            {
                getDataResult.token = rssreader.getData();
            }

            import mx.events.CollectionEvent;
            import valueObjects.Item;

            protected function fixEntityReferences(event:CollectionEvent):void
            {
                myList.labelFunction = replaceEntity;

                function replaceEntity(item:Item):String
                {
                    var p1:RegExp = /(&quot;)/ig; // perhaps add more here later
                    var thisString:String = item.title.replace(p1, "");
                    trace(thisString);
                    return thisString;

                }
            }

            protected function myList_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
            {

                var RSSItem:Object = myList.dataProvider.getItemAt(event.newIndex);
                navigator.pushView(DetailsView, RSSItem);
            }

            private function refreshList():void

            {

                    Object(navigator.activeView).getData();  

            }
        ]]>

    </fx:Script>
    <s:actionContent>
        <s:Button label="Refresh"
                  click="refreshList()"/>
    </s:actionContent>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:CallResponder id="getDataResult"/>
        <rssreader:Rssreader id="rssreader"/>
        <s:CallResponder id="getDataResult2"/>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:List bottom="0"
            change="myList_changeHandler(event)"
            id="myList"
            itemRenderer="views.IconItemRenderer"
            labelField="title"
            left="0"
            right="0"
            top="0">
        <s:AsyncListView list="{getDataResult.lastResult}"
                         collectionChange="fixEntityReferences(event)"/>

    </s:List>
</s:View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Roky,

```
        private var dataLoaded : Boolean = false;

        protected function getData(force : Boolean = false) : void
        {
            if (!dataLoaded || force)
            {
                getDataResult.token = rssreader.getData();
                dataLoaded = true;
            }
        }
```

In your refresh button you can call getData(true) to force it to refresh even if the data is already loaded.

Comment: Heeey Shaun "the nice guy" :)) I have a one error with this code. On line "protected function getData(force : Boolean = false) : void" error is: 1021: Duplicate function definition.

Comment: You must have pasted but not replaced your existing one.  AS3 doesn't allow overloading methods which is what you're telling it to do.  Overloading is when you have different "signatures" which is to say the data types for the method call are different but the method name is the same.  AS3 doesn't allow you to do that so you have to just paste this over your existing method... or now that you have two delete your old one.

Comment: Glad I still had the source around :)

Comment: Hm, I replace code, but when I`m scrolling on List (first view) still must have a data connection ON. When I set off data connection or wi-fi during using app (only scrolling on a list) images not showing.

Comment: That's actually expected behavior.  List type display objects in Flex use a thing called item renderer recycling to avoid creating as many UIComponents as there are elements in your dataprovider.  Basically things off screen aren't created until they come on screen.  If you want it to initially cache all the images you have to handle it "manually" so that they're stored in memory ready to use instead of being fetched on the fly.  It shouldn't be too difficult but will require some custom code I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Shaun thanks a loooot! If you have a solution, please post it here, for all other users with same problem :) This loading data is really need for any type of rss readers.